# Yii2 не отключается CORS

Tags: yii2, cors

Мой контроллер

```
namespace app\controllers;

use common\models\User;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\Cors;

class UserController extends ActiveController {
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

    public static function allowedDomains() {
        return [
            '*',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors() {
        return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [

            // For cross-domain AJAX request
            'corsFilter'  => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                'cors'  => [
                    // restrict access to domains:
                    'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['*'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                    'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,                 // Cache (seconds)
                ],
            ],

        ]);
    }
}
```

В ответе от сервера заголовки не приходят
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было изменить

```
'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
```

На

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => static::allowedDomains(),
```